# embedVar not working on python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently coding a discord bot, and am trying to create a command that is similar to the "pls gayrate" that the Dank Memer bot has. This is my code so far:

```py
@client.command()
async def gayrate(ctx):
    zeroto100 = random.randint(0, 100)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title = "gayrate lmao", description = "how gay are ya", color = 0xffffff)
    embedVar.add_field(name = f"{message.author}", value = "is", zeroto100, "percent gay :gay_pride_flag:"
    await ctx.send (embed = embedVar)
```

When I run this code, it returns:

```
await ctx.send (embed = embedVar)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have all the other necessary things to run the bot working, It's just this part that isn't. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things you are missing:

1. You are missing a `)` after value on the line before `await ctx.send`.
2. You should use `f-strings` for string formatting.
3. It should be `ctx.message.author` instead of `message.author`.
4. Command decorator needs `()`.

Here is the revised code:

```py
@client.command()
async def gayrate(ctx):
    zeroto100 = random.randint(0, 100)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="gayrate lmao", description="how gay are ya", color=0xffffff)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f"{ctx.message.author}", value=f"is {zeroto100} percent gay :gay_pride_flag:")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```